# index and match for currency conversion

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am currently working on a billing report from multiple countries. The billings are set on particular country's currency. So I am trying to convert them to USD for the conversion rate of billing date.

I have managed to download historical exchange rate and it is monthly but still works for me. I am kind of confuse how to match and index them when there are multiple years (30 years) and currencies to be exchanged and the dates are different.

This is how historical exchange rate table looks like:

[image: table]

and part of the billing, I want to fill the `amount $` column:

[image: table with amount]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is my understanding correct?

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(H2,"YYYY-MM")=TEXT($A$2:$A$13,"YYYY-MM"))*(J2=$B$1:$E$1),I2*$B$2:$E$13)
```

[image]

Comment: That's a perfect solution. Thank you for your effort @Lee

Comment: It's good one @Lee prefect 10 ☺

Answer (score 0):

You can get the rate with

```
=index('ExchangeRateSheet'!$A$1:$F$20000,match(BillDate,'ExchangeRateSheet'!A:A,0),match(BillCurrency,'ExchangeRateSheet'!$1:$1,0))
```

It's difficult to provide a more precise formula since I cannot see your sheet names and cell addresses. Adjust according to the above logic.

Once you have the rate, use that in your conversion formula, i.e. multiply the fees by the rate.

Comment: thanks for your reply, https://imgur.com/a/V9AoIfq I have just upload the picture with column name as example one. Can you please modify it according to that? I've tried your formula to mine but it did not work somehow. I believe i made a mistake.